# Helidon SE + CDI

Tags: helidon

How can we start a Helidon 4.0 SE server with just CDI feature (as provided by default in Helidon MP)? What are the dependency that are needed to be added to helison-se to enable CDI and what are the changes that are required at application startup to load the scoped beans ?

Answer (score 0):

CDI feature is made exclusively for Helidon MP